# SSIS Woes: Dynamic OData Connection for Same SharePoint List on Multiple Sites

Tags: sharepoint, ssis, odata

I am having an issue using an `OData` SharePoint List Source with a dynamically changing connection string (inside the `OData` Connection Manager). The OData Source inside of my Data Flow Task fails to validate with the error message, “Cannot acquire a managed connection from the run-time connection manager” when executing the DFT from a parent package.

I have done some extensive Googling, and combed the forums relentlessly; however, I have not found anything that seems to offer a solution to this problem. Any help figuring out a solution would be greatly appreciated!

Here is the general flow of the main SSIS package:

1. Truncate staging table
2. Get all Site Collection URLs and their GUIDs from SQL Table
3. Execute Package Task for each site collection (foreach ADO loop container)

   1. Extract data from UserInformationList (OData source)
   2. Add a column for the GUID of this site collection
   3. Load the data into staging table
4. etc. . .

Main Package:
[image: SSIS Main Package Control Flow]

Child Package Control FLow:
[image: SSIS UserInformationList Package Control Flow]

E-L UserInformationList DFT:
[image: SSIS UserInformationList Data Flow Task]

Package Output With Error Message:
[image: SSIS Package Output Containing Error Message]

When testing the entire solution, everything (tasks, parameters, variables, etc.) behaves properly until 3.1(see above), when the `OData` Source fails during validation. The only aspects of the source and connection manager that change are the URL and ConnectionString for the connection manager; the specific SharePoint list that I access on each site never changes. When the solution enters the child package, the URL and ConnectionString for the Connection Manager are properly set, prior to entering the DFT.

When testing the child package via the Execute Package Task, using hard-coded parameter values, the child package fails to validate.

When testing just the child package, there are no errors and the list information is stored in the database, as expected. However, with individual testing, the `OData` Connection Manager uses the default value of the package parameters.

Things I have tried so far:

- Set `DelayValidation` to True
- Changing the debugging runtime from 64 to 32 bit (and back again)
- Use collection to specify the list (in the `OData` Source Editor)
- Use resource path to specify the list (in the `OData` Source Editor)
- Running the child package as a Farm Admin
- Running the solution as Farm Admin

Other information:

- SharePoint 2013
- Data Tools for Visual Studios 2012
- Microsoft’s `OData` Source for SQL Server 2012

Answer (score 0):

i think you don't have access to the source sharepoint or you are not passing the right credentials thats why you are getting this error. Please use valid connection and test your connections.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue while I was reading the URL for OData source from database. In my case, I was passing old value for URL which has changed in the SharePoint side that is, the DB had URL value http://sharepointsite/News but the actual site was modified by user to http://sharepointsite/NewsUpdated 
So, check the passing URL value in your case in case you still having this issue

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and it looks like at the moment of starting for loop container, you need to provide a valid value for the URL variable, it will be overwritten this or the other way, but if I would go with "0" or null I would get the same error as you